# Relationship between pointwise convergence and $L^2$ convergence with continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let ${f_n}$ be Riemann integrable on [a,b] for all n and $f, g\in C[a, b]$(continuous).

Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ and $f_n \rightarrow g$ pointwise. Is it necessarily $f=g$?

I'm not sure even it's true or not. (I can't prove it and disprove it..) How do you think about

this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. It is a standard result (in a more general context) that $L^p$ convergence implies pointwise almost everywhere convergence for a  subsequence. Hence, we have

$$f_{n_k} \to f \quad \text{a.e.}$$

On the other hand, $f_{n_k} \to g$ a.e. and the result follows.

The reference that comes to mind for this is Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, Chapter 3. Given that you're really only considering continuous functions, there likely some simplifications that can be made in the proof.

Comment: Oh... This problem comes from a Fourier series chapter in elementary analysis 2 course. I haven't even thought it's related to such deep stuff. Thanks!